# onLocationChanged never called in FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

There are some other questions on SO about the same problem, but I guess that the answers a bit old and maybe not applicable to my scenario. In the code below, the method `onLocationChanged` is never called. I also tried to send new Locations from the android emulator, but it's just never called. Any idea what is going wrong here?

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleApiClient apiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myview);

        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        apiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        System.out.println("yeah, this works");

        // I also tried to set some properties on the location request like interval, etc. but they have no effect
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, request, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        System.out.println("this is never shown");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        System.out.println("this is never shown");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("this line is never called ");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got permissions?

Comment: go through this example once, you may solve it from this: http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/

Comment: hey @shaft i think you have to first check for googlePlay is available or not and second check for location provider after that  go further in code

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had gradle warnings about "all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification". In my case I changed

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

With the new dependencies list, gradle is happy and the example just works. Hope this can help someone.